# Python groupby/convert a triple join table to nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

From a SQL stored procedure that performs a join on 3 tables I get the data below.

```
    data = [
        {"service_order_number": "ABC", "item_id": 0, "ticket_id": 10},
        {"service_order_number": "ABC", "item_id": 0, "ticket_id": 11},
        {"service_order_number": "ABC", "item_id": 1, "ticket_id": 12},
        {"service_order_number": "DEF", "item_id": 3, "ticket_id": 13},
        {"service_order_number": "DEF", "item_id": 3, "ticket_id": 14},
        {"service_order_number": "DEF", "item_id": 3, "ticket_id": 15}]
```

I would like to group the data on service_order_number and item_id to return a list of dicts like below.

```
[
  {
    "service_order_number": "ABC",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "item_id": 0,
        "tickets": [
          {
            "ticket_id": 10
          },
          {
            "ticket_id": 11
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "item_id": 1,
        "tickets": [
          {
            "ticket_id": 12
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "service_order_number": "DEF",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "item_id": 3,
        "tickets": [
          {
            "ticket_id": 13
          },
          {
            "ticket_id": 14
          },
          {
            "ticket_id": 15
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The hierarchy would be service_order_number > item_id > ticket_id

Is there an easy way to convert this data into my desired structure?

Comment: Have you looked at dictionary comprehensions? What have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you need this data structure specifically? It doesn't use any of the strengths of a dictionary. Have you considered using the values as keys in the outer dictionaries? And finally, have you considered a pandas DataFrame as a data structure, which would allow you to easily access specifically keyed values as well, while being very easy to construct?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using [`defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```py
import json
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for item in data:
    (my_dict[item['service_order_number']][item['item_id']]
      .append({'ticket_id': item['ticket_id']}))

res = [{'service_order_number': service_order_number, 
            'line_items': [{'item_id': item_id, 'tickets': tickets} 
            for item_id, tickets in item_group.items()]}
        for service_order_number, item_group in my_dict.items()
]
print(json.dumps(res, indent=1, default=int))
```

---

```
[
 {
  "service_order_number": "ABC",
  "line_items": [
   {
    "item_id": 0,
    "tickets": [
     {
      "ticket_id": 10
     },
     {
      "ticket_id": 11
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "item_id": 1,
    "tickets": [
     {
      "ticket_id": 12
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "service_order_number": "DEF",
  "line_items": [
   {
    "item_id": 3,
    "tickets": [
     {
      "ticket_id": 13
     },
     {
      "ticket_id": 14
     },
     {
      "ticket_id": 15
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Comment: Minor note: If the `defaultdict` might ever need to be pickled (or, like me, you just hate `lambda`s), you can use `my_dict = defaultdict(defaultdict(list).copy)`; same behavior as `my_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`, but the factory function is picklable (`lambda`s aren't).